# VertexConnectivity and FindVertexCut disagree

Tags: graphs-and-networks, bugs, version-9

I'm trying to use Mathematica to compute the minimal vertex cut for graphs. From what I understood, VertexConnectivity of a graph should correspond to the number of vertices in the minimal vertex cut.

However, when I use Mathematica 9.0 on a graph, I get a VertexConnectivity of 1, but the minimal cut computed by Mathematica has 33.

This seems strange! Is this a bug, or am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated!

Here's a link to the text used to generate the graph which I am testing: http://pastebin.com/WWk0Gk8G
VertexConnectivity and FindVertexCut are the functions I'm using.

Regards,
Dave

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: **VertexConnectivity is buggy in v9, unfortunately.** The correct answer is 33, not 1.  I marked as a duplicate of the thread discussing this.  You can either upgrade to v10 (which has this fixed) or use igraph as a workaround (as described in the link).

Comment: Thanks for the help! Strange that such a bug managed to get through.

Answer (score 0):

You may see that removing a single vertex doesn't disconnects your graph. It's a bug,as noted in the comments:

```
And @@ Thread[ Length /@  ConnectedComponents /@ (VertexDelete[g, #] & /@ VertexList@g) == 1]

(*  True *)
```